# How to resolve 2 different methods in one function on Apollo GraphQL resolver?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, graphql, apollo

I have this resolver

```
SLAccount: (_, { imsUserId, imsToken }, context) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    addAuth(context, imsUserId, imsToken);
    context.model
      .getUserAccount(getEndpoint(imsUserId, imsToken))
      .then(resolve)
      .catch(reject);
  }),
```

But there is a another method/model I need to include there:

```
  getHardware(endpoint) {
    return this.connector
      .get(
        `${endpoint}/...`,
      )
      .catch(res => this.handleError(res));
  }
```

So I'll need something like this:

```
SLAccount: (_, { imsUserId, imsToken }, context) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    addAuth(context, imsUserId, imsToken);
    context.model
      .getUserAccount(getEndpoint(imsUserId, imsToken))
      .then(resolve)
      .catch(reject);

    context.model
      .getHardware(getEndpoint(imsUserId, imsToken))
      .then(resolve)
      .catch(reject);
  }),
```

The thing is that I don't need to call them at the same time, sometimes I need just one of those methods/models inside `SLAccount`.

So what would be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL is driven by requirements (query).

When you need `account` just query for that. When you need `account` and related `hardware` just query for both - additional resolver will be called automatically. This is a basic idea behind graphQL. Look for any tutorial covering relations in graphQL.